# Load all data from cursor

Tags: java, android

I have a Db table:

```
'aid' INTEGER,
'tid' INTEGER,
```

Which represents connection between activity and task, so multiple tasks could be connected to one activity using their ids:

```
aid tid
1   5
1   9
1   11
```

So activity with `id=1` is connected with tasks with `ids=5,9,11`.

I load all this data during the launch of the app and put it in `SparseArray`, where keys of this array are activity ids (`aid`), and values of this array are arrays with task ids (`long[]`).

The function looks like this:

```
public final void setRawCursor(final Cursor cursor) {
        if (cursor != null) {
            long aid, aidPrev = INVALID;
            final FastLongKeySparseArray<long[]> map = mTaskPinMap.getMap();
            final FastLongStack stack = new FastLongStack(25);
            try {
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    aid = cursor.getLong(TaskPin.AID_);
                    if (aidPrev != INVALID
                            && aid != aidPrev) {
                        map.append(aidPrev, stack.toArray(new long[stack.size()]));
                        stack.clear();
                    }
                    stack.push(cursor.getLong(TaskPin.TID_));
                    aidPrev = aid;
                }
                if (aidPrev != INVALID) map.append(aidPrev, stack.toArray(new long[stack.size()]));
            } finally {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
        mIsDataReady = true;
    }
```

My purpose to save as much memories as possible, and do not make pressure on GC. I use `long[]` instead of `ArrayList` because this data could be modified in rear cases, so it is not hard to add new ids to `long[]` by coping the array, and I think to save memory with such turn.

What do you think? Is it possible to eliminate put to the map after the loop?